# What is the difference between «entendre parler» and «entendre dire»?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

Both «entendre parler» and «entendre dire» are translated by my dictionary as "to hear about" but I've been corrected for using one instead of the other before so I'm wondering what's the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is similar but the preposition used after these expressions differs: *entendre parler **de** quelque chose* vs *entendre dire **que** quelque chose s'est passé/va se passer*.

For example:

> *J'ai entendu parler d'une affaire de corruption.*

> *J'ai entendu dire qu'il y avait une affaire de corruption.*

*Entendre parler* is close to "hear about" while *entendre dire* is close to *entendre quelqu'un dire* thus closer to "hear someone telling".